# How do you delete a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I accidentally created the tag "angu" on the main site. I tried looking for a delete button a little bit but I didn't find it. How do I delete it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags that don't have questions get automatically deleted within 24 hours. Simply remove the tag from the question and wait for a bit.